# GoLand code analysis has been suspended, how to re-start it?

Tags: go, goland

Goland shows code analysis has been suspended at the top right.
I have tried Following things:

1. Restart GOLAND,
2. Re- installing goland
3. Memory utilisation is also not heavy.

Nothing seems to work yet, any other things that I can check?[image]

Comment: Are you using power saving mode?

Comment: No, Not using power saving mode @JayVasant

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Press `shift` twice and in the context window type `Inspect Code Actions`
- Select it and press `Enter`
- Then from another context menu choose `Configure Current File Analysis`
- Choose `All Problems`

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is in the parenthesis under the `Code analysis has been suspended` message.

The `(Doing file refresh)` part refers to the fact that the IDE is currently scanning the known folders such as the project directory, the Go SDK and `GOPATH` or `GOPATH/pkg/mod` (aka `GOMODCACHE` since Go 1.15) to check for any differences from the last IDE usage to the new session.

This should happen in two scenarios: you are starting a completely new IDE session or you have installed a new dependency.

If this takes too long to finish, please check your settings for what the `GOPATH` or the project directory is or open an issue [on our tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go). Please attach the IDE logs zip file from `Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostics Data...` from the IDE.